# How do you ignore Whitespace when using CsvHelper, CsvReader.Read()?

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

When using the CsvHelper library and in particular the `CsvReader.Read()` function, is there a way to ignore blank records and/or whitespace?

I need to return the raw `string[]` but was hoping, I could do some cleanup functions when parsing with the library.

I've checked Github and `CsvReader.Read()` seems to use **SkipEmptyRecords** but this doesn't work for me as I have whitespace.

Here's my csv file, its encoded in UTF8 without BOM.

[image]

I've tried ASCII encoding, just in case I missed something but that didn't work either.
If no one knows I'll chat to Josh and submit a git request with a fix.

Reference: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: It does seem to use SkipEmptyRecords - https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs#L177

Comment: I did see that but it doesn't appear to work for me, it checks for nulls but not whitespace. Question modified to reflect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best bet is to fix the library yourself.

The problem is that the `Read` method uses the `SkipEmptyRecords` setting and the `IsRecordEmpty` method to determine if it should skip a field or not:

```
while (this.configuration.SkipEmptyRecords && this.IsRecordEmpty(false));
```

However the IsRecordEmpty() method is not perfectly implemented to support your scenario, because it uses the following code:

```
Enumerable.All<string>((IEnumerable<string>) this.currentRecord, new Func<string, bool>(string.IsNullOrEmpty));
```

That does not work because your strings are not null or empty. In my opinion combining Trimming with SkipEmptyRecords could work in theory:

```
 csv.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
 csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
```

But again the trimming is not utilized when checking if the field is empty or not, so i am pretty sure your only option is to fix the library yourself and to use the trimming in the IsRecordEmpty() method OR use **IsNullOrWhiteSpace** instead of IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: Cool.. push a fix for all of us ;)

Comment: Excellent fix Ralph. The pull request has been merged and is in release 2.9.0 on NuGet.