# Convert value to int

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to convert a value from a CSV file using CsvHelper. The value itself is an integer but the value inside the csv contains a whitespace e.g. "0 " or "12 ".

How can I get it to work now? On StackOverFlow I found this thread but the trimming doesn't apply to the binding. According to a comment from the creator of this library it should since V2.9.0.

[How do you ignore Whitespace when using CsvHelper, CsvReader.Read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104057/how-do-you-ignore-whitespace-when-using-csvhelper-csvreader-read)

I try to read my CSV in this way:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(datei))
{
    CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
    configuration.BadDataFound = null;
    configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;
    

    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration))
    {
        ArtikeldatenLieferant = csv.GetRecords<AllnetArtikel>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Edit:

This is one line of my CSV which results in this issue:

```
Nr.;ALLNET-Artikelnummer;Hersteller-Artikelnummer;Hersteller;Produktbezeichnung;EAN Nummer;Kategorieebene1;Kategorieebene2;Kategorieebene3;HEK;Artikelzustand;UVP;Produktbeschreibung;Gewicht;Lagerbestand 
9234;193301;AL-MSUC-SUF-S;Audiocodes Live;Audiocodes Live - AL-MSUC-SUF-S;;Telekommunikation;Voice over IP;Voice over IP - Gateway Support;2739,13;neu;3043,48;"AudioCodes Live non-recurring setup fee, for each customer site with up to 500 users. Includes delivery, Planning and Design consulting service, Implementation service (configuration and basic verification) for AudioCodes hardware or software, and cutover support into production for a single event. Does not include Project Management.;0,001;0
```

Edit2: Here is the AllnetArtikel class.

```
public class AllnetArtikel
    {
        
        [Name("Nr.")]
        public string Nr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("ALLNET-Artikelnummer")]
        public string AllnetArtiNr{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Hersteller-Artikelnummer")]
        public string HerstellerArtiNr{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Hersteller")]
        public string Hersteller{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Produktbezeichnung")]
        public string Produktbezeichnung{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("EAN Nummer")]
        public string EAN{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Kategorieebene1")]
        public string Kategorie1{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Kategorieebene2")]
        public string Kategorie2{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Kategorieebene3")]
        public string Kategorie3{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("HEK")]
        public decimal HEK{ get; set; }
        [Name("Artikelzustand")]
        public string Zustand{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("UVP")]
        public decimal UVP{ get; set; }
        [Name("Produktbeschreibung")]
        public string Produktbeschreibung{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Name("Gewicht")]
        [Default(-1)]
        public decimal Gewicht{ get; set; }
        [Name("Lagerbestand")]
        public int Lagerbestand { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion/ add pepper an salt to taste

Answer (score 2):

**Final Update**

The issue ended up being a quote in a field and the quote was not escaped or the field contained in quotes.  `;"AudioCodes ... Management.;`.  Since the quote was a part of the data that was needed, the solution was to change the configuration mode to `NoEscape`. [This mode will ignore quotes and escape characters.](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/#section-24)

```cs
configuration.Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape;
```

**Update**

Any string that works with `int.Parse` should work with `CsvHelper`.  For instance `int.Parse("0     ") == 0`.  Since having extra whitespace is not an issue and it works when you change your integer field to string, I'm going to take a guess that your issue is actually with an empty value.  `CsvHelper` is unable to convert any empty values into an `int`. If that is the case, you have two choices.

Either turn your integer field into a `Nullable<int>`

```cs
void Main()
{
    CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));

    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id;Name\n1;Joe\n;Jenny"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or give your integer field a default value.

```cs
void Main()
{
    CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));

    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id;Name\n1;Joe\n;Jenny"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Default(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Original**

Are you sure you aren't getting an exception for something else? I can put in as many spaces after the number as I want and it still reads it correctly.

```cs
void Main()
{
    CsvConfiguration configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id;Name\n1    ;Joe\n10 ;Jenny"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, configuration))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }   
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes. When I change my integeer field to string it works perfectly. The trim options also trims my value but it doesn't allow me to get it working for an int

Comment: Since it works when you change your integer field to a string, I think your issue may actually be with an empty value.  You are likely getting an error message like "The conversion cannot be performed. Text: '' MemberType: System.Int32" If you notice `Text: ''` that means its trying to convert an empty string.  I added to my answer on how to deal with that if that is indeed the issue.

Comment: Hi David, nope the Text: '' part says MARKERSPACE

Comment: That sounds like your issue then.  `CsvHelper` can't convert "MARKERSPACE" to an int.

Comment: I added an example line of my CSV to my original question. This one is unable to parse the field for "Gewicht" and "Lagerbestand" but I do not know why.

Comment: Can you add the `AllnetArtikel` class and the error you are getting?  I see in your example CSV that there is an opening quote with `"AudioCodes`, but no closing quote at `Management.;`.  That is going to cause an issue.  You could try `configuration.Mode = CsvMode.Escape` to see if that works.

Comment: yes this is right. The " stands for inches. The CSV has no quotes.

Comment: I added the class in my question above. Is there any way to disable quoting completly?

Comment: configuration.Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape is excatly what I was searching. It works now. ;)

Comment: Glad it works!  Just be aware that any ; or newline character in a column like `Productbeschriebung` will cause issues, since they will no longer be able to be escaped by enclosing them in quotes.  I would also suggest that in the future you start off your question with an example of CSV that fails and any error messages that you get.